# useParams data as an state object key in useSelector with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

I need to access the state data using a key that I'm getting from useParams.
Like this:

```
export const MainPageSection = (props:MainPageSectionPropsType) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const currentSection = params.section
    const excursions:ExcursionsCollectionResponseType = 
    useSelector((state:AppRootStateType)=> state[currentSection])
 ...
}
```

Got an error TS2538: Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. But I can't use conditionals here, so I wrapped this component in a container to get check for params value there and pass it to my component. Like that:

```
export const MainPageSection = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const currentSection = params.section
    if (!currentSection) return
    return <MainPageSectionChild param={currentSection} title={'Title'}/>
}
export const MainPageSectionChild = (props:MainPageSectionPropsType) => {
    const excursions:ExcursionsCollectionResponseType = useSelector((state:AppRootStateType)=> state[props.param])
    const excursion:ExcursionCollectionResponseItemType = excursions[0]
```

But now there's another error:
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'EmptyObject & { excursions: ExcursionsCollectionResponseType; tours: ToursCollectionResponseType; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'EmptyObject & { excursions: ExcursionsCollectionResponseType; tours: ToursCollectionResponseType; }'.

Can anybody give a clue on how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you are doing this because you cannot call `useSelector` conditionally.
 However you can call it on every component render as you have to do but with a conditional value:

```js
export const MainPageSection = (props:MainPageSectionPropsType) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const currentSection = params.section
  const excursions:ExcursionsCollectionResponseType | undefined = 
  useSelector(currentSection ? (state:AppRootStateType)=> state[currentSection] : () => {})
}
```

During the first render when `currentSection` is `undefined`, `excursions` will be `undefined` since `useSelector` is called with an empty function `() => {}`, after that when the component rerenders and `currentSection` get the expected value, `useSelector` is called with `(state:AppRootStateType)=> state[currentSection]` and `excursions` should recive the expected data.

Now you just have to handle that

```js
//...

if(!excursions) return null
return (
 <>
  //...
 </>
)
```

Comment: "you are doing this because you cannot call useSelector conditionally" - Yeah I'm not seeing where any `useSelector` hook is being conditionally called anywhere in the post. Can you clarify/correct this part of your answer?

Comment: @DrewReese he would like to call `useSelector` only when `params.section` is truthy. that's why he created `MainPageSectionChild`

Comment: That's completely valid JSX though and doesn't violate the rules of hooks since `useSelector` is unconditionally called when the `MainPageSectionChild` is mounted/rendered.

Comment: @DrewReese I know, and if you reread the question you'll see that the op faced that so he decided to created `MainPageSectionChild` and call it only when `currentSection` is defined so he no longer face the ` Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type` error. in fact this fixed the first problem but causes the second one. so this answer come with a fix to the original problem.

Comment: Right, OP said they already addressed the initial problem they had with the implementation, none of which involved conditionally calling the `useSelector` hook. I'm trying point out that this part of your answer is irrelevant since it wasn't even a problem the OP said they had.

Comment: @DrewReese you might be right, but if the OP didn't mention this part in the question I would never suggest that

Comment: Yes, Ahmed understood me correctly. Sorry if the question was confusing, I'm a not a native speaker of English

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me how you configured the store and defined the `AppRootStateType` type ? If you followed [this guide](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) correctly, you would have a `useAppSelector`, that does not require you to do `(state: Type) => ...` . Anyway, I think something is not right in the configuration of the store.